# what algorithm is used by GMP for prime field inversion (mpz_invert)?

Tags: c++, algorithm, primes, gmp, inverse

What is the algorithm used by GMP to invert a element in a finite field?

Answer (score 4):

It uses extended GCD as implemented in `mpz_gcdext`: https://fossies.org/dox/gmp-6.1.0/mpz_2invert_8c_source.html .

Comment: See section 15.3.4 of the GMP manual: [https://gmplib.org/manual/Extended-GCD.html#Extended-GCD](https://gmplib.org/manual/Extended-GCD.html#Extended-GCD)

Comment: Specifically, it calls `mpz_gcdext` with a NULL argument for one of the Bézout coefficients - since it's not required. `(g, z, NULL, x, modulus)`. The least non-negative residue (the inverse) will be within: `+/- modulus` if `(z < 0)`. This is due to gcdext returning one of two possible 'minimal' coefficient pairs.